# Отправка данных из одинаковых форм на сайте

Tags: php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте,задам глупый вопрос) на страницы сайта есть несколько одинаковых форм для отправки данных.

```
<form>
<input type="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="phone" />
<button>Send</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$name = trim($_GET["name"]);
$phone = trim($_GET["phone"]);
```

Отправляются данные только с последней формы, с предыдущих форм получаю пустые переменные.
Пришлось в каждой форме изменять `name` например `name="phone1"` и, соответственно, отдельный файл с PHP.

Как можно это исправить, чтобы не создавать отдельный обработчик для каждой формы?

Comment: Тип формы ставьте `post`. Имена полей именуйте как элементы массива `email[1]`, `email[2]`, ... И одну форму делайте, раз все данные хотите разом отправить.

Answer (score 1):

Может вопрос не так понял, но думаю вам нужно что то такое.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit1">Send</button>
</form>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit2">Send</button>
</form>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit3">Send</button>
</form>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
        var_dump($_POST);
    }elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
        var_dump($_POST);
    }elseif(isset($_POST['submit3'])){
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
```